# Select statement with result even if there isn't in the db

Tags: sql, select, case

I have this table with all my attachment on specific customer order and I want to select only one kind of attachement, but I want to see the line even if there is no attachment. Is there a way to do so?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT 
  Comm.No_Com, 
    CASE WHEN Attachement.EntityID IS NULL OR Attachement.ATS_CategoryOfAttachmentCode='DESSIN'
        THEN Attachement.FileName
        ELSE ' '
    END AS Dessin

    FROM Comm
    INNER JOIN Attachement
    ON Comm.COH_Id=Attachement.EntityID
```

Comment: That's the difference between INNER JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT 
    Comm.No_Com, 
    CASE WHEN Attachement.EntityID IS NULL OR Attachement.ATS_CategoryOfAttachmentCode='DESSIN'
        THEN Attachement.FileName
        ELSE ' '
    END AS Dessin
FROM Comm
LEFT OUTER JOIN Attachement
ON Comm.COH_Id=Attachement.EntityID AND Attachment.Kind = 'DesiredKind'
```

Comment: I Still have the problem that it gives me 10 lines if I have 10 attachements that I don't want to see (other kind of attachement). Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.